# How can I get total amount value for each different user in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want sum all **308** values in *userprofileid* column to get the total amount of the values for that user in the *amount* column

This image shows `GROUPBY(userprofileid, amount)`

[image]

My goal:

```
308    664,878
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Measure** as below-

```
total = sum(table_name[amount])
```

now add **userprofileid** and newly created measure **Total** to a table visual and you will get your desired output.

But, if you need only sum for profile 308, you need something as below-

```
Total_308_ = 
calculate(
    sum(table_name[amount]),
    filter(
        ALL(table_name),
        table_name[userprofileid] = 308
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I need another table. It's like a GROUPBY but only showing one user and the sum of amount for each one

Comment: Then your sample data do not explain the scenario correctly. Add them to the question at least considering 2 profileid.

Comment: Thanks man, I changed the image for another example with more userprofiles

Comment: This is your physical base table? or logical with GROUP BY implemented?

Comment: Best if you can upload a sample PBI file with sample data somewhere in Google or other drive. Then people can download the file and check the possibilities. Don't forget to show your expected output form that sample data.

Comment: It's my logical table with GROUPBY, finally I made it with PowerQuery but I wanted with DAX. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a measure

```
Measure =
SUMX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[userpofileid] ), SUM ( 'Table'[amount] ) )
```

If you need a table

```
tbl =
GROUPBY (
    'Table',
    'Table'[userpofileid],
    "amount", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), 'Table'[amount] )
)
```